# MongoDB .NET Driver ProjectionDefinition Slice method does not work

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I work with a MongoDB collection in ASP.NET Core 3 application via a compatible MongoDB Driver.
The document structure in my collection includes, among others, an array field (lets call it "steps").
My task is to project the collection with all its fields, while fetching the last two members of this array per document.

This is a mongo query which I run in Robo 3T:

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').find({}, {"steps" : {$slice: -2}})
```

It works perfectly, and projects the data in the exact same way that I want it to.
However, I cannot successfully copy this to my ASP.NET app.

This is how I build the projection in C#:

```
ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument> fieldsBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection;
ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> stepsArrayProjection = fieldsBuilder.Slice("steps", -2);
List<MyCollectionModel> result = await myMongoService.GetDataByFilterDefinitionAsync(filter, stepsArrayProjection);
```

where filter is a predefined `FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>` that I use.
When I try to run the query in my ASP.NET controller via Swagger, I get an exception, which says:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command aggregate failed: Expression $slice takes at least 2 arguments, and at most 3, but 1 were passed in.
```

What I am trying to understand, is why is it any different from the $slice projection that I use while querying the collection in Robo 3T. It seems that I pass 2 the field name to slice, and which array members to take.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like, in the first code, you use `Find` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#slice-projection, but in the second `Aggregation` (inside `GetDataByFilterDefinitionAsync`): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/#exp._S_slice which requires at least 2 arguments. It's different commands. If you want to emulate `Find` MQ command you should use `Find` c# methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a difference and actually, the C# driver is pretty consistent with the Mongo shell command. I would do it like follows, though:

```
var filter = Builders<MyCollectionModel>.Filter.Empty;
var project = Builders<MyCollectionModel>.Projection.Slice(x => x.Steps, skip);
var result = context.MyMongoCollection.Find(filter).Project(project).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The problem was that in the GetDataByFilterDefinitionAsync() method, there was an Aggregate() method in use, which uses a different flavor of Slice. I did not notice it at first because the mongoService is a DLL library from an external project which I did not work with before.